# Getting an option as default value in a lightning-combobox component

Tags: lightning-web-components, default-value, lightning-combobox

I have a lightning-combobox component, that gets options from a javascript method.
What I am trying to do is to get one of those options, as default value in the html component.

Javascript method is something like this:

```
    get options() {
    var options = [];
        if(this.sortData.sortRules){
            this.sortData.sortRules.forEach(ele =>{
                options.push({label:ele.label + ' ' + ele.direction , value:ele.sortRuleId});
            });
        }
    return options;
    }
```

The html element is like this:

```
<lightning-combobox
      name="progress"
      label="Sort:"
      value={value}
      placeholder="Sorting by"
      options={options}
 </lightning-combobox>
```

I want to know how to get the first option from ***options[]*** as default value in the combobox.

Anyone that can help me with this?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the options are available in connected callback, you can set a default value like this:

```
import { LightningElement } from "lwc";

export default class Combobox extends LightningElement {

  options = [{label: 'a', value: 1}, {label: 'b', value: 2}]

  connectedCallback() {
    this.value = this.options[0].value;
  }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work in connected callback. The webstore stops working if I'm doing it like this.

Comment: Then you'll need to do the same when your options are set. You may want to write a setter.

Comment: Then you'll need to do the same when your options are set. You may want to write a setter.